# Django: Name error at ROUTE/

Tags: python, django, url-routing, django-urls

I've a Django project `advisor` with `core` application.

My routes are separated into a small group of files.

I try to include them from the main `urls.py`, but django fails with the following exception

```
NameError at /ask

name 'advisor' is not defined

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/ask
Django Version:  1.2.4
Exception Type:  NameError
Exception Value:  

name 'advisor' is not defined
```

Here is the code that include routes under the `ask/` url, though `advisor.core` registered at `setting.py`

`(r'^ask/$', include(advisor.core.urls.ask)),`

and this is `advisor.core.urls.ask` contents

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns

urlpatterns = patterns(
    'core.views.ask',
    r'^$', 'ask',
    r'^private/$', 'private',
    r'^ngos/$', 'ngos'
)
```

What is going wrong with my code?

Sultan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(r'^ask/$', include('advisor.core.urls.ask')),
```

Comment: I've removed `advisor` and seem things began to work and for now I got `AttributeError at /ask`

Comment: Also exception value is `'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'`

Comment: Try `url(r'^ask/$', include('advisor.core.urls.ask')),`